# distance to conic from origin optimization

Tags: optimization, conic-sections, lagrange-multiplier

I want to optimize the distance from the origin to a generalized conic function (optimize for min/max distance).

What I have so far:
$$ A>0, B^2<AC$$ 
Conic equation: $$Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 = 1,$$
distance equation: $$(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}.$$ Since it will make math easier and won't matter for distance, I thought to do distance squared, so optimizing $$d^2=(x^2 + y^2).$$

Using Lagrange method:

$$F(x,y,s)=x^2 + y^2 + s(Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 - 1)$$
$$\nabla F(x,y,s)=(\partial F/\partial x, \partial F/\partial y,\partial F/\partial s)=(0,0,0)$$ for optimization

$$
\begin{align}
\partial F/\partial x & = 0 = 2x + 2Asx + 2Bsy \\
\partial F/\partial y & = 0 = 2y + 2Csy + 2Bsx \\
\partial F/\partial s & = 0 = Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 - 1
\end{align}
$$

I can get here, I just can't do the algebra to solve it, and if I try using an online source, it doesn't have enough computing power for free users, I figure there is some trick to do, but I can't for the life of me find it. Thank you all.

Comment: Depending on what $A$, $B$ and $C$ are, there might not be a maximum. Are there any other constraints on your conic?

Comment: No other constraints, though the book does say what the maximum distance we are supposed to find is (not the minimum however). Max= (A + C + ((A - C)^2 + 4B^2)^(1/2))/(2AC - 2B^2)

Comment: Well, what happen to this maximum when $AC-B^2$?

Comment: I apologize, I realize now that it says the following: A>0 and B^2<AC.

Comment: Please learn how to format math in LaTeX so that MathJax can display the equations properly. Start with the [Basic Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: That’s important information. You’ve got a rotated ellipse. That might give you some ideas of where the max and min ought to be.

Comment: I've been playing around with the algebra since I made the post (and some beforehand) and despite graphing it out and seeing what I'm looking for, I've made no headway. At this point, the question is more of an algebra question that calculus question, as I understand that calculus just fine.

Comment: I don't know if it's going to be any simpler, but you might try a more geometrical approach: at the min (or max), the line from the origin to $(x, y)$  is going to be perpendicular to the tangent at the same place, i.e. the product of the slopes of the two lines should be $-1$ (although this gets in trouble with horizontal or vertical lines).